# Wordpress - style.css classes are not being applied

Tags: html, css, wordpress, xampp

I have really strange problem. Yesterday on my localhost (I am using XAMPP) everything was good and I finished my website for client. Today when I want to show him my work, everything looks different. I discovered, that many classes from style.css are not being applied. It seems like wordpress is loading old version of style.css, BUT when I am modyfing some properties of basic classes from template I can see changes. Please help me, what should I do? I have never had that kind of a problem. I tried cleaning cache, updating wordpress, but nothing happened.

[Screenshot with sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQhUr.jpg)

[Example of a problem (class is not applied)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXldj.jpg) - it is just one example. Many my classes are now not being applied.

My class:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px){
.statek{
background-image:url("http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/grafika-maska-gradient-01.jpg") ;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-size:cover;
height:1570px;
max-width:100%;
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a child theme? Can you screencap your file structure so I can see what's going on?

Comment: I edited my post. If you need more infos, just write me.

Comment: when you view your site now did you clear the css/html cache? hit Fn + F5 on most browsers

Comment: Are you using a child theme or did you just edit the theme directly? Also, your files (including your css file) have that ?ver tag on the end, which could be problematic. Can you load your css file on your browser? The url would be http://localhost:8888/style.css?ver=4.6.1

Comment: Well I dont know what happened, cleaning cache gives no effects, anyway thank you for your replies. I just deleted my own classes and rewrite them.